# The mesh of my model is distorting when I try to pose it. Help!

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, pose-mode

I'm a major beginner at blender, but I tried following a few tutorials and ended up being able to make a low-poly base model and rig it, or so I thought. When I tried to pose the model it got super distorted.  If anyone has any advice, I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

The model after I just rigged it:
[image: The model after I just rigged it]

The model after trying to pose it:
[image: The model after trying to pose it]

Comment: Try unparenting the mesh from the armature, select the mesh and in edit mode select all the vertices and choose "Recalculate normals". Then in object mode Apply (Ctrl A) rot and scale to both mesh and armature, then redo the armature parenting. If this doesn't solve, please upload your file.

Comment: That fixed the problem.  Thank you so much!